# Sail to discover those magic islands

Tags: word-usage, imperative-sentences

> Sail to discover those magic islands

Sail - here it means, travel by ship on or across (a sea).

How grammatical the use of the word "sail" here? (even if we think little poetically)

Answer (score 2):

It would be grammatical, if it is being used in the imperative mood.

Answer (score 1):

An advertisement might say,

"Sail away and discover those magical islands."

Is that what you want? Your usage of "Sail to" in your example is troubling.

[FWIW I've said this before elsewhere, sorry - but as a learner you will do well to stick to what you hear said in its specific context].